# Drupal Form API Facebook Login

Tags: 7, forms, social-network

I have Facebook for Drupal installed on my Drupal instance. My application and everything is working fine. I want to make it so one of my custom content types requires Facebook login to submit. Can I do this using the hook_form_alter()? This will be for anonymous users. I want them to see the content type (which they can already see) but once they fill in the fields and hit submit the form will require for them to be logged in through Facebook. Should i use that hook or can i accomplish this in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the Drupal for Facebook module has User Management capabilities which allows me to automatically assign a temporary role to any users authenticated via Facebook. I added a role and changed the permissions to allow for the posting of my custom content type. Everything is working now! Hope this helps someone!!